# Apache Server won't shutdwon

Tags: apache, server

When I try and shutdown Apache (httpd) on Centos 7, the process is immediately restarted and new forks occur. I've used systemctl stop httpd, apachectl stop, killall -9 httpd, etc etc etc. Each time, the same status is printed out:

```
httpd.service - The Apache HTTP Server
Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/httpd.service; disabled; vendor preset: disabled)
Active: active (running) since Thu 2017-02-02 22:32:33 EST; 9min ago
  Docs: man:httpd(8)
        man:apachectl(8)
Process: 3521 ExecStop=/bin/kill -WINCH ${MAINPID} (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 3527 (httpd)
 Status: "Total requests: 325; Current requests/sec: 1; Current traffic:  32KB/sec"
 CGroup: /system.slice/httpd.service
        |-3527 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
        |-3530 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
        |-3531 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
        |-3532 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
        |-3533 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
        |-3535 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
        |-3605 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
        |-3606 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
        |-3607 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
        |-3634 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
        `-3647 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND

Feb 02 22:32:33 <host name> systemd[1]: Starting The Apache HTTP Server...
Feb 02 22:32:33 <host name> httpd[3527]: [Thu Feb 02 22:32:33.673324 2017] [so:warn] [pid 3527] AH01574: module cosign_module is already loaded, skipping
Feb 02 22:32:33 <host name> httpd[3527]: [Thu Feb 02 22:32:33.676044 2017] [so:warn] [pid 3527] AH01574: module cosign_module is already loaded, skipping
Feb 02 22:32:33 <host name> httpd[3527]: [Thu Feb 02 22:32:33.676946 2017] [so:warn] [pid 3527] AH01574: module cosign_module is already loaded, skipping
Feb 02 22:32:33 <host name> httpd[3527]: [Thu Feb 02 22:32:33.678075 2017] [so:warn] [pid 3527] AH01574: module cosign_module is already loaded, skipping
Feb 02 22:32:33 <host name> httpd[3527]: AH00548: NameVirtualHost has no effect and will be removed in the next release /etc/httpd/conf.d/<external server>.conf:1
Feb 02 22:32:33 <host name> systemd[1]: Started The Apache HTTP Server.
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The answer turned out to be a service called Monit running, it was set to restart httpd and varnish anytime they were shut down.